# Mouseover doesn't work on an animated path

Tags: javascript, path, jquery-animate, raphael

I used the following code to change the `stroke-width` when `mouseover` the path, but it doesn't work... I have checked many solutions on this matter, they seem to use the same solution as mine. My `canvas` is `Raphael("svgContainer", 100, 100);`

```
 function drawPath(i,floorlevel,pointsNum){


  var x1 = floorlevel[i].x;
  var y1 = floorlevel[i].y;
  var x2 = floorlevel[i+1].x;
  var y2 = floorlevel[i+1].y;
  var p = canvas.path("M"+x1 +" "+ y1);
  p.attr("stroke", get_random_color());
  p.attr("stroke-width",4);
  p.attr("id",floorlevel[i].node+floorlevel[i+1].node);


  p.animate({path:"M"+x1 +" "+ y1+ " L" + x2 +" "+ y2}, 1000);

  var set = canvas.set();

  var hoverIn = function() {
      this.attr({"stroke-width": 10});
  };

  var hoverOut = function() {
      this.attr({"stroke-width": 10});    
  }

  p.hover(hoverIn, hoverOut, p, p);
  set.push(p);
}
```

Comment: create a jsfiddle.net please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine when I sub in dummy values for the arguments you pass to the function:

http://jsfiddle.net/hKCDg/

I noticed you have the same `stroke-width` for `hoverIn` and `hoverOut`, which defeats the purpose.

```
  var hoverIn = function() {
      this.attr({"stroke-width": 10});
  };

  var hoverOut = function() {
      this.attr({"stroke-width": 10});    
  };
```

I changed the latter to `5` in the demo here for visual effect.

Perhaps there's an error in the values you pass to the function?